# JCL for running COBOL program calling subprogram

Tags: cobol, mainframe, jcl

I have one COBOL pgm A which is calling another COBOL pgm B.
In pgm B I need one file.How can I write JCL so that I would be able to access this file in pgm B? I have written select clause and FD entry for this file in B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must include a [DD statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=reference-dd-statement) in the JCL for the step that executes Program A.

If the file exists, that's quite easy.

```
//ABCDEFGH DD DISP=SHR,DSN=your.file.name.here
```

Where ABCDEFGH is the name you uses in your SELECT statement in Program B.

If you are creating a new file, you must take into account the estimated space your file will use and where you want to place it.

```
//ABCDEFGH DD DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),
//            DSN=your.file.name.here,
//            AVGREC=K,
//            RECFM=FB,
//            LRECL=your-lrecl-here,
//            MGMTCLAS=your-management-class-here,
//            SPACE=(your-lrecl-here,(primary-number-of-records,secondary),RLSE)
```

This is just freehand, you really should look at the [JCL Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=mvs-zos-jcl-reference) and [JCL User's Guide](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=mvs-zos-jcl-users-guide).

Comment: From the JCL perspective it doesn't matter whether program `A` processes the file or program `B` does because they are both execute in the same step.

Comment: I created JCL...and also updated my main pgm and sub pgm by adding same select clause for this file and in FD section declared this file as EXTERNAL. I tested my JCL . It is working fine. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Include the DD Statement in the step.
2. Program B does not even have to be COBOL.
3. Ideally design so that program B is a service program - opens, closes,   reads, writes re-writes according to
   request and your needs. It will make your life a lot easier if this encapsulation is anticipated.

I have seen this where B is assembler and flushes writes to disk periodically when not run interactively, but writes immediately when debugging.

Comment: You'd not need a program change for "flushing", just change the DD to unblocked (assuming blocking hasn't been hardcoded in the program). I'm not at all sure what benefit that would give you, but that's how you'd do it. No code involved.

Comment: The benefit is for debugging. Products such as Expeditor or Intertest say. Buffering in production did historically yield performance gains. Possibly a red herring. I was trying to demonstrate the full "service" nature of the sub module. Typically such a lot of file handling is performed at a top level.

Comment: Well, a debugging tool where you have to modify the behaviour of the program to use it, ever, in any circumstance, doesn't seem like much cop to me. I'm sure they can show the buffer areas, but there we go. At least an explanation.